# Setting right for relative positioned div not working

Tags: html, css

I thought left,right,top,bottom works for absolute, and relative positioned objects, but when I tried relative positioning on a div, suddenly, it doesn't work anymore. What am I doing wrong?

```css
#outer {
border: 1px solid red;
width: 50%;
height: 50%;
}
#inner {
border: 1px solid blue;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id = 'outer'>
<div id = 'inner'> Hello World! </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the `#outer` to be `position: relative` and the `#inner` to be `position: absolute`.

Adding a little more detail:
Look at http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

relative = The element is positioned relative to its normal position, so "left:20" adds 20 pixels to the element's LEFT position

In your case combining `right: 0` with `position: relative` on `#inner` does nothing, because you told the layout engine to move `#inner` such that its right boundary is 0 from its normal position.

Comment: In that case, why does changing it to left: 50px move it 50px from the left?

Comment: Because you are specifying a non-null value of 50px. Just note that this is relative to its normal position, not its parent's position.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your `height:50%` and `width:50%` will not work here. For them to work, their parent container must have a predefined height or width, or the element itself must be positioned `absolute`. In case it is positioned `absolute`, the element will have a height and width equal to 50% of the height and width of the **next higher parent element, which is positioned `absolute` or `relative`**; and if there is no such element, it's height and width will be 50% of that of the viewport.

As far as the `position:relative` property is concerned, let me explain it with an example of a div positioned relative, and with a property of `right:20px` on it. The word relative here means relative to the original position of the div, that is its position if there was no position property specified for it. And the right property shifts the elements **from the right, 20px towards the left**. It does not shift it towards the right. Of course, as I said earlier, the shift is relative to its **original** position.

Also, I had specified two position preperties by mistake. Know that in such a case, the property that is specified later is the one that counts. This is called **overriding** the property defined earlier.

```css
#outer {
border: 1px solid red;
height:50%;
width:50%;
position:absolute;
}
#inner {
border: 1px solid blue;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
right : 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id = 'outer'>
<div id = 'inner'> Hello World! </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do here. First, why did you set 2 different positions in #outer, and second of all, taking off both of those 2 positions in #outer, run the code again, and you'll get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

@agdhruv "Know that in such a case, the property that is specified later is the one that counts. This is called overriding the property defined earlier."

My tests and info from the web (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/right) indicate, that this statement is not always correct in the case of the left and right properties.

Quote from Mozilla site (MDN):

> When both left and right are defined, if not prevented from doing so by other properties, the element will stretch to satisfy both. If the element cannot stretch to satisfy both -- for example, if a width is declared -- the position of the element is over-constrained. When this is the case, the left value has precedence when the container is left-to-right; the right value has precedence when the container is right-to-left.